# Access jQuery Controls on Server Side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, controls, server-side

Is there a library or framework built for invoking jQuery / Javascript functions from the server side?

For example, say I'm using a jQuery UI datepicker control on my page.  The datepicker's format (e.g., MM/dd/yyyy) is configurable on a per-user basis.  In this scenario I'd have to retrieve user preferences on the server, record the user-chosen format in a hidden control, send the HTML page to the client, and finally extract the format from the hidden control on the client side.  Does any library exist that facilitates this long-winded process?

Comment: What server? PHP? ASP.NET? Java [+...]?

Comment: You can write inline javascript in such cases inside the HTML that you're generating through your server side script.

Comment: Sorry guys.  I'm on the dark side.  Microsoft ASP.NET 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use custom attributes for this sort of thing.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="myDatePicker" ClientIDMode="Static" 
  format="MM/dd/yyyy" />
```

Render the attribute when you render the page based on the user settings, then the client code can just grab it whenever it's needed and apply as appropriate:

```
var format = $('#myDatePicker').attr('format');
```

I sometimes use a simple infrastructure for this purpose which can JSON+base64 encode objects to include in a generic "data" property, then unwind it at the client, to add more complex information to a control.

In other situations I just grab the settings when I need them from the client using a service called through ajax, but this way is more efficient, if you already know what it is when the page is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to incorporate some sort of server side scripting language such as MySQL/PHP to pull the users preferences, then it shouldn't be too hard to bundle in. You would just need to make the storage "dynamic" in that it accepts a wide range of date formats, or convert to a more standardized format.

Until I know what languages you are using, or some sample code, its hard for me to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how your site and page is setup. But, if you are storing the user's selected date picker format in a cookie or session variable you could expose this value through a string property on the page (e.g. DatePickerFormat) and then make the jQuery datepicker dateFormat dynamic something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#idOfDataPickerControl').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', '<%=DatePickerFormat%>');
});
```